# Which application architecture i should follow?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

I have started a new application. Currently i have organized it as a Angular & WebApi **Single Page Application** but i am bit confused. This application is a kind of invoicing application when i am going to use some third party apis as well like **Intuit**. 
I want to make a solid decision before proceed further that which application architecture should i follow. Like between a Single Page application or asn traditional MVC 5.0 application.

If you guys have any idea please share. Thanks

Comment: i think that it can help you:
https://blog.svpino.com/2014/10/15/is-a-single-page-application-what-you-really-need
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28737/pros-and-cons-of-a-single-page-site-versus-a-multi-page-site

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it depends on what kind of application it is. If your application is not that much big and high priority on UX or design (like for marketing / support / Informational kind of  applications) then you should go with SPA.

But If your application is data driven means performing on huge data and result / data / information is the high priority then you should go with traditional MVC 5.0 application.

This isn't solve your problem yet. As you mentioned you are using WEb API, please look at the post as well https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246380/should-we-call-web-api-from-mvc-application-in-same-solution

Answer (score 0):

This is not in any shape or form a definitive and complete answer. Just a quick opinion.

For your front-end I would recommend to go with HTML 5 based single page Angular application that is completely separate from your API. Here are some pros:

1. Angular is a very popular choice nowadays and you will have a lot of support (code samples, libraries, articles, SO questions, etc.)
2. By separating your Angular app from your Web API (back-end code) you will start with a very clean modular architecture that in the future will allow you to (1) easily re-user your API for another app, (2) port your app to other platforms like iOS and Android using PhoneGap.

I would also use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) + [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to speed up the development. If you build mobile-first, look into [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). If you want cool animations, look into [Famous](http://famo.us/).

For your API I would choose Web API 2 and I would separate it in 3 layers: 
 1. Web/API layer. Your controllers, models, input validation.
 2. Services layer. Your business logic (e.g. InvoicesService, StatementsService, UsersService, etc.).
 3. Infrastructure layer. Everything related to data access and persistence (e.g. database access).

If you have a database, then Entity Framework 6 is your friend.

Comment: Thanks...So you mean doind a Single Page Application is better in that manner...Like i might dealing with 15k Records...Is that fine.

Comment: 15K records where? In the database? I just made a general suggestion that HTML5 Angular app + separate Web API is better than your classic MVC 5 application. If you have to retrieve and display a lot of data, HTML5 Angular becomes an even stronger choice because it forces you to render you HTML first and then retrieve data from API instead of rendering data to the page on the server.